# elasticsearch "block until refresh"/"wait for doc to be searchable" alternatives

Tags: performance, optimization, elasticsearch

I need to index/update a document in Elasticsearch and wait until it is searchable (refresh has been done). There is a related issue on Github: https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/1063

I won't force the refresh because it impacts indexing performances and I will need to perform this operation really often.
I tried to wait for 1 second as described in the Github issue. It works really well as long as Elasticsearch is not under pressure, but when there is not much RAM left (which might happen occasionally) I have seen the refresh take up to 5 or 6 seconds. Thus I tried another way.

I have written an helper function in my backend that waits for the “searchable” document to reach a given version. It is quite simple:

```
- GET the document with realtime=false
- if there is a result
    - if result.version >= wanted.version.
        Return
    - else
        wait a little more and retry
- else if the doc is not found
    - HEAD the document with realtime=true (test if the doc exists in the transaction log)
        - if the doc is found (then it has just been created)
            wait a little more and retry
        - else
            Return. (the doc might have been created and deleted really fast)
```

The wanted version is the version returned by elasticsearch when the document has been indexed.

This algorithm works but you can see that it is far from being perfect.

- first it will make more calls to elasticsearch when it is under pressure, which is not a really good idea.
- I have seen elastic search reset the version number when a doc has been deleted for some time. If for some reason the function misses that, we might wait until the doc reaches this version again. (that’s why I also added a timeout).

Does someone have a better solution? Scaling automatically is not an acceptable answer right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Guillaume Massé said, a solution is about to be merged in Elasticsearch https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/1063#issuecomment-223368867

Thus I would advise to wait for the builtin functionality rather than implementing a custom solution.

Comment: I think its worth pointing out that a side effect of Elasticsearch being open source and developed openly is that just because someone from the Elasticsearch team publicly proposes a thing doesn't mean its company policy or even a good idea. We make almost all proposals publicly because that is how open source should work. You had a better idea and linked me to the stackoverflow post about it, for example.

Comment: Yes I completely agree. What I meant was just "no better solution I've heard of, for the time being". I didn't want to say "this is the way to use Elasticsearch". Thank you for pointing that out. I'll fix the answer to make it more clear.

Comment: It's about to be closed/solved: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/1063#issuecomment-223368867

Comment: Thanks @GuillaumeMassé

Comment: they say in the PR that it will be available in elasticsearch 5.0.0